# replace Makefile to _Makefile in Makefile

Tags: sed, makefile, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-extended/ethtool/ethtool_5.4.bb#n32

```
do_install_ptest () {
   cp ${B}/Makefile                 ${D}${PTEST_PATH}
   install ${B}/test-cmdline        ${D}${PTEST_PATH}
   install ${B}/test-features       ${D}${PTEST_PATH}
   install ${B}/ethtool             ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/ethtool
   sed -i 's/^Makefile/_Makefile/'  ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/Makefile
}
```

In the last line:

```
   sed -i 's/^Makefile/_Makefile/'  ${D}${PTEST_PATH}/Makefile
```

I don't know what's the purpose to replace 'Makefile' to '_Makefile' in Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably some detail about how the Makefile itself works, you'll have to read the Makefile in detail to work that out.